# Is $|xy|$ differentiable in $(0,0)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Is $f(x,y) = |xy|$ differentiable in $(0,0)$? I have no idea how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $|xy| \le ||(x,y)||^2$...

Comment: Depends on which norm one uses ;-)

Comment: @quid Heh. Good of you to clarify that...

Answer (score 0):

$\vert f(x,y)\vert \leq x^2+y^2$, hence $f(x,y)= o(\sqrt {x^2+y^2})$, and $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$, with $f'(0,0)=(0,0)$

Answer (score 0):

First note that the partial derivatives exists and are $0$. Thus, if it differentiable the derivative ought to be $0$.

Thus you check if

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{|xy|}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$$
is $0$ or not.

It will turn out it is $0$. Thus the function is differentiable and its derivative  at $(0,0)$ vanishes. 
(In view of this the initial observation is not really needed anymore.)