# Tangent plane of $z=|xy|$ at point $(0, 0)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

$f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is given as $f(x_1, x_2)=|x_1x_2|$. This function has all directional derivatives($D_u f(\mathbf{0})$) for all direction, and it is equal to $0$. So I want to conclude that $f(x_1, x_2)$ has a tangent plane at $(0, 0)$, given as $z=0$.

However, the question wants to prove me that this graph does not have a tangent plane, and that $f$ is not differentiable at point $0$.

The problem can be wrong, it's a dusty book, but I was wondering if I was right, and if this argument is enough.

Comment: Consider the line $(\sqrt t,\sqrt t)$

Comment: @MartinR   Isn’t $D_uf(0, 0)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(hu_1, hu_2)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}h|u_1u_2|=0$

?

Comment: What is $u\hspace{1pt}$?

Comment: @ElliotG Any vector of length 1, with arbitrary direction.

Comment: @JoshuaWoo: You are right, my fault.

Comment: @MartinR I know that in some cases all of the directional derivatives exist, yet the function is not differentiable. How can I guarantee that it is not the case for this function, and make a better proof?

Comment: @JoshuaWoo: The function *is* diffentiable at $(0, 0)$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1832065/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks a lot.

Comment: Now I'm confused lol